# Tkinter RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window

Tags: python, tkinter, runtime-error

So I'm trying to draw an image to a tkinter canvas in python, and keep getting the error in the title. I have a reference to `tkinter.Tk()`, I've set it as the canvas's master, I've packed the canvas, and run the mainloop. This all happens upon program start. Then, I call `gui.drawentity()` in main.py, which attempts to create an image and draw it to the canvas.

**gui.py**

```
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="green")

canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()

def drawentity(entity):
    imgPath = data.getimagepath(entity.img, entity.imgType)
    img = None
    try:
        img = tk.PhotoImage(imgPath)
        canvas.create_image(entity.x, entity.y, img)
    except IOError as e: print(e)
    finally:
        if not isinstance(img, type(None)): img.close()
```

**main.py**

```
e = player.Player(100, 200, "Ball_Grayed.png", 3)
gui.drawentity(e)
```

**data.py**

```
 cd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "resources")
 def getimagepath(imgName, imgType):
     return os.path.join(cd, imgType, imgName)
```

When running `py main.py`, I get the following output:

```
File "S:\Users\Sean\Google Drive\cs\personal\BallAdventure\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    gui.drawentity(e)
  File "S:\Users\Sean\Google Drive\cs\personal\BallAdventure\gui.py", line 22, in drawentity
    img = tk.PhotoImage(imgPath)
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4026, in __init__
    master = _get_default_root('create image')
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 297, in _get_default_root
    raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")
RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window
```

Everything looks fine to me, can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: try moving `root.mainloop()` to the end of your code.

Comment: @Nesi Didn't quite work but lead me to the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(see Nesi's comment)

It seems the `tk.mainloop()` call *blocks* (execution of the program halts there). I was only getting the error after exiting the window, which makes sense as the program essentially goes into a `while True` loop when `mainloop()` is called. Since I had been manually destroying the default root window, there was nothing to draw to upon continuing the code.

So, be careful where you put `mainloop()`, and know that it *blocks*.

([source/more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29159217/4036475))